# What happens when you're not online and the drafts start?

Tags: fantasy-lcs

If I join a league and then go offline. And in the meanwhile the host/starter of the league start the draft selection. How will I get the players? Are they assigned automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All player/team/alt selections are drafted randomly if you are offline during the drafting phase.

However, you can still manage your team until the matches start (starting line ups, flex player, etc)

After this weeks matches are played, you can participate the new draft again. If you are online, it is manual drafting, if you are offline, it is assigining random but the picks will be according to the suggested order so you will still have a decent team.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are talking about, but if you are in select champion phase, and your internet goes down, then if the time goes to zero, then you are kicked of the match and your friends will return to room. Is that what you asked?

Comment: I am talking about fantasy lcs not normal games

Comment: you tagged league of legends!

Comment: It is technically league of legends related